# when would next integer $n+1$ be a prime in a given range of $p_*< p< p_*^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, markov-chains

*Conjecture*

that along the sequence of natural numbers $n\in\Bbb N$, if *walking* upwards $1,2,3,4,\ldots,n,n+1,\ldots,$ from every integer to the next (starting with $n=1$), the probability $\phi_p$ that every next integer $n+1$ would be a prime in a given range of $p_*< p< p_*^2$, equals:

$$\Phi_{p_*}=\prod_{p=2}^{p_*} \phi^{(\text{Markov }1)}_p=\prod_{p=2}^{p_*} \frac{p-2}{p-1}$$

(transition probability in accordance to a *Markov chain first order* (indexed *Markov 1*); and taking into account our knowledge of the current state $n$ before we *walk* to $n+1$).

***Question: is the above conjecture mathematically correct?***

PS: the above is related to the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414990/does-the-twin-prime-constant-0-66-equals-the-conditional-probability-upon-a-mark) and [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401892/prime-divisibility-in-a-prime-square-bandtwidth).

Answer (score 0):

You could not have a fixed transition probability "walking upwards" in a given range $p_*<p<p_*^2$ since these intervals are overlapping. For example, for $n$ in $31,32,32,\ldots,100$ you would have the probability equal to $\Phi_{11},\Phi_{13},\Phi_{17}$ and others even though those differ.

It's not clear what you mean by "probability" here. This doesn't look like a Markov process. When $n=6k+1$, "taking into account our knowledge of the current state $n$" we can say that the probability that $n+1,n+2,n+3$ are prime is zero.

Comment: Let me better understand you, perhaps we talk about different things. The above conjecture is based on following points (1) in a range of $]p_*, p_*^2[$ all integers which are non-divisible by **ALL** primes in the range $[2,p_*]$ are primes; (2) along the abovementioned *walk* the probability  that every next integer $n+1$ would be non-divisible by a given prime $p$, equals $\frac{p-2}{p-1}$; (3) the joint probability that every next integer $n+1$ in  $]p_*, p_*^2[$ would be non-divisible by **ALL** primes in the range $[2,p_*]$, equals $\prod_{p=2}^{p_\max} \frac{p-2}{p-1}$.